# Can the elements of a list always be sorted into a canonical order?

Tags: list-manipulation

As the title states - does a unique order exist for any *Mathematica* list to be sorted by the `Sort[]` function (or as returned by a function that treats lists as sets)?

While I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, the kinds of elements you can throw into a *Mathematica* list seems so general and varied (numbers, strings, symbols, images, graphs, other lists, etc., etc.) that I thought to make sure.

(The reason this question occurred to me is an exercise question asked in the book I just started learning *Mathematica* from: Write a function `SubsetQ[list1, list2]` that checks whether `list1` is a subset of `list2`. My solution is

```
SubsetQ[lis1_, lis2_] := Intersection[lis1, lis2] == Union[lis1, {}]
(* thanks to Simon Woods' correction, and assuming Intersection and Union sort canonically *)
```

but that implicitly assumes that the two lists on either side of the equality check will be sorted in the same order.)

Comment: "Write a function `SubsetQ[]`..." - you've already seen `MemberQ[]`?

Comment: Yes, I have. What solution would you like to suggest? (If it involves iteration, then that occurred to me, but since the book hasn't gotten to it yet I didn't consider it any further.)

Comment: There is a canonical order. See : http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-A.3.9

Comment: Note that `DeleteDuplicates` doesn't sort, so for example you get `False` for `SubsetQ[{2, 1}, {3, 2, 1}]`. You probably meant to use `Union`

Comment: Yeah, there is a canonical order. But the docs for `Intersection[]`don't mention using it. That is not the case for example with `Complement[]`, where the doc says **The list returned by Complement is sorted into standard order.**

Comment: @belisarius, Aky I guess functions that implement (mathematical) set-algebra (like `Intersection`, `Union`, `Complement`) **always** sort the elements of their results. Other list manipulating functions usually don't.

Comment: @IstvánZachar You're probably right. Now ... how to prove the sort is done consistently in the standard order?  :D

Comment: @SimonWoods I mistakenly presumed that it did. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @belisarius According to v. 9 documentation, Intersection " gives a sorted list of the elements common ..."

Comment: @Aky But no reference to "standard order". Compare it with the doc for `Complement[]` ... And yes, I know I'm being picky

Comment: @belisarius I would say since in *Mathematica* anything can be a list-element, `Intersection` must deal with general lists, which implies that its sorting function should be one that can sort any expression type. And since canonical sorting is such (and I don't think any other sorting is used generally in *Mathematica*) I would *presume* `Intersection` uses canonical sorting. To prove it would require someone to test all the specifications of the standard order linked by andre above. So in short: no, I don't know how to quickly test `Intersection`'s sorting order :)

Comment: @IstvánZachar I saw a similar list in the documentation for Sort[]. Is the general case of dissimilar elements and elements such as Images, Graphs, etc. covered by the point on how mma sorts expressions?

Comment: @IstvánZachar So we are clear here. Sort is ordering by `Faith[]` :)

Comment: @belisarius ... or perhaps by `ObscureOrderedQ[{#1, #2}, Method -> "RosicrucianFuzzy", "SortHebrewChars" -> No!, "ConfuseUserFurther" -> True]&`. And no one will ever know.

Comment: From my experience, the answer is yes - the default sorting function is the same for `Union`, `Intersection` and `Complement`. As a side note, you could avoid this problem in this particular case by using something like `SubsetQ[lis1_, lis2_] := Complement[list1, list2] === {}`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Nice solution! Wish it had occurred to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As several others have pointed out, there exists a [canonical ordering](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-A.3.9) for any *Mathematica* expression. Quoting the list:

> - Integers, rational and approximate real numbers are ordered by their numerical values.
> - Complex numbers are ordered by their real parts, and in the event of a tie, by the absolute values of their imaginary parts.
> - Symbols are ordered according to their names, and in the event of a tie, by their contexts.
> - Expressions are usually ordered by comparing their parts in a depth-first manner. Shorter expressions come first.
> - Powers and products are treated specially, and are ordered to correspond to terms in a polynomial.
> - Strings are ordered as they would be in a dictionary, with the upper-case versions of letters coming after lower-case ones. Ordinary
>     letters appear first, followed in order by script, Gothic,
>     double-struck, Greek and Hebrew. Mathematical operators appear in
>     order of decreasing precedence.

In your specific case, you can avoid having to sort anything by just taking the `Complement`, as [Leonid mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22569/can-the-elements-of-a-list-always-be-sorted-into-a-canonical-order#comment70337_22569):

```
SubsetQ[lis1_, lis2_] := Complement[list1, list2] === {}
```